# How can i pass a 2d array to JTable in Netbeans efficiently?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, multidimensional-array

I have a method that returns a 2D String array and I need to show this in my GUI. I used NetBeans to add a JTable, and set it up that when I click a button

```
jTable1 = new JTable(method(),ColNames);
```

runs. (the JTable is declared by NetBeans somewhere) `ColNames` is a hard-coded String array. The table doesn't change. Is this wrong? Is there no one-line way to do this?

Comment: use custom code option by right clicking on jtable

Comment: I Can't. The 2D array gets filled after the jTable is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I used NetBeans to add a JTable, and set it up that when I click a button*

I'm assuming you mean NetBeans GUI builder to place the `JTable` and layout your components. If so then you don't have to re-create your table on button's click but set a new table model instead. Something like this:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(method(),ColNames);
table.setModel(model);
```

See:

- [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html)
- [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Answer (score 3):

you need to change table [model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) when you clicked the button.

```
DefaultTableModel newmodel = new DefaultTableModel(method(), columnNames);
jTable1.setModel(newmodel);
```